# C# technique used with Style property of Font class

Tags: c#, winforms

Can someone help explain the following bit of code.

```
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily,
            richTextBox1.Font.Size,
            richTextBox1.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Underline);
```

The code relates to the onclick event in a form and is used to toggle the underline font style on and off. I think I understand Exclusive Or, if either input is true then the result is true but if both are true or both are false then the output is false.

I don't understand how this applies to the Style property though, how does it store this data, is the Style property not just one enum value that records the enum. I don't understand how this property can record the results of more than one value, or is it not doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Style` property is a *flags* `enum` where the values are defined as powers of two: 1, 2, 4, 8. They can be combined since they're each only a single bit in a different position. Say, using OR to get bold-italic text:

```
  0001 Bold   = 1
| 0010 Italic = 2
-----------------
  0011 Bold/Italic = 3
```

And XOR will flip it, as you say:

```
  0011 Bold/Italic = 3
^ 0010 Italic      = 2
----------------------
  0001 Bold        = 1
```

and

```
  0001 Bold   = 1
^ 0010 Italic = 2
-----------------
  0011 Bold/Italic = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The style enum has the [flags attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) set. This allows it to be treated as a binary number where each bit represents a different style attribute. Binary arithmetic can be used to compose a collection of styles, eg bold and italic into one value.